# Why is the output weights matrix initialized in a different way as the word embedding matrix in word2vec?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, word-embeddings, truncated-normal-distribution

I was plagued by this problem while reading the [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/word2vec/index.html). There the word embedding is intialized as follows:

```
embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
```

while the output words matrix in a differenct way:

```
nce_weights = tf.Variable(
  tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                      stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
```

Why should the variance of the output weights distribution be limited to be within a range(and the range be 1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)? Is it set to make the backpropagation tractable as [here described](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks)?

> In order to make the learning process tractable, it is a common
>   practice to truncate the gradients for backpropagation to a fixed
>   number (num_steps) of unrolled steps.

Answer (score 2):

In this [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) it reads that:

> One should generally initialize weights with a small amount of noise
>   for symmetry breaking, and to prevent 0 gradients. Since we're using
>   ReLU neurons, it is also good practice to initialize them **with a
>   slightly positive initial bias to avoid "dead neurons"**.

Dig into the code a bit I find that it is the [ReLU neuron](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/131c3a67a7b8d27fd918e0bc5bddb3cb086de57e/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L169) that is used, hence it is reasonable that the same(to avoid "dead neurons") may apply to his issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the input and output weights are initialized differently. It probably doesn't matter all that much.

The truncated back-propagation is a completely separate issue and has nothing to do with the way that the weights are initialized.